# How to calculate the max transfers per frame and the remaining bytes in USB protocol?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

Could someone explain the attached table and how the values are calculated? ([the table is taken from the official usb 2.0 specification page 42](http://www.poweredusb.org/pdf/usb20.pdf)).

What I could understand is just the relation between the *bytes/frame* and *bytes/second* (as in Full Speed the second consists of 1000 frames). But how is the *max transfers*, the *bytes remaining*, *frame bandwidth per transfer*, and the *bytes/frame* calculated?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how is the max transfers,

The max transfers is the number of complete packets of the chosen size that can be sent in a frame.

> the bytes remaining,

Once you've sent *max transfers* * *frame size*, this is the number of bytes that are left over in the frame.

> and the bytes/frame calculated?

Bytes/frame are the number of payload bytes sent in the frame, or the number of *bytes/transfer* * *max transfers*.

So, if you send one byte, there's 46 bytes in the packet that carries that byte.  The *max transfers* is the number of packets in a frame, which is 1495 bytes, or 1495/46 = 32.5.  We're not counting the half-packet, so that becomes 32, which takes up 32*46=1472 bytes.  23 of the 1495 are unused, so that's *bytes remaining*.  Your *bytes/frame*, since each transfer passed only one byte, is 32*1=32.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I almost got everything, just few questions yet. How did you get this *1495*? Shouldn't it be Max Speed (12 MBit) / 8 (to get it in byte) / 1000 to get per frame, which gives 1500 byte/frame? Could you also show where did *frame bandwidth per transfer* come from?

Comment: I got 1495 from calculations from the table...I'm not sure where the other 5 bytes went, maybe into a frame sync.  The *frame bandwidth per transfer* is the percentage of the 1495 bytes are used for each packet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess the 5 bytes are disappeared because of the rounding of the fractions according to your calculations.